# how do I include a python cgi script into a html page

Tags: python, html, cgi

I want to display to values at a html webpage. I have a Python CGI script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
#import cgi
sensor = BMP085.BMP085()

temperature=sensor.read_temperature()
pressure=sensor.read_pressure()
pressure=pressure/100.0

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<body>'
print "%.2f °C" %temperature
print "%.2f hPa" %pressure
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

When I call it from the console it works fine, but when I include it via iframe 
`<iframe src="daten.py"></iframe>` 
only a white page apears. The file is executable and the webserver supports CGI. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does it work if you open `daten.py` in your browser? i.e. `http://yourdevice/daten.py`? Are both the html file and daten.py in the same folder?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I only get an empty page. Both files are in the same folder

Comment: Then I'm afraid your server is not set up correctly :/ Any errors in your server logs?